# Is it possible to manipulate this series/generating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I have come across a [generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) that is similar to another generating function.

First, some preliminaries.  I call a closed form a function like $\frac{1}{1-x}$.  In other words, a closed form does not involve a summation or integral, but rather a bunch of arithmetic that describes a generating function.

Now, I have come across a closed form of the generating function:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty{X_k y^k} = X_0 + X_1 y^1 + X_2 y^2 + \dots$$

where the $X_k$'s are themselves generating functions:

$$X_k = \frac{1}{1-(z_k)} = 1 + (z_k) + (z_k)^2 + \dots$$

I'd like to convert the $X_k$'s into $z_k$'s.  In other words, each coefficient of the original series is $\frac{1}{1-(z_k)}$.  I'd like to convert from that to just $z_k$.  I'm wondering if there is some sort of transformation that can do this all at once.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

**IMPORTANT EXPLANATION**

I know how to get the $z$ values in the formula.  What I really want is to *change* the formula into something that is not equal to the original formula.  In other words, say I have:

$$y\frac{1}{1-z_1}+y^2\frac{1}{1-z_2}$$

Then I want:

$$y z_1 + y^2 z_2$$

Comment: Why not just substitute the formula you have for $X_k$ into the sum? You will get something like $$\sum_{k, l} z_k^l y^k$$ This is fairly messy, but I think it has to be that way, unless $z_k$ is something nice.

Comment: @Feanor: The problem is that I have a closed form.  I start with something like $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-y(\frac{1}{1-z})}$.  This isn't the best example, but I really can't modify the individual $X_k$'s because the $z$'s are mixed together and are not in the form of a summation.  I have everything in closed form, and that's my real problem.  I'd like to modify the closed forms, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not all at once - don't worry about convergence,
just substitute:

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty{X_k y^k} 
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{ y^k}{1-z_k}} 
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty y^k\sum_{j=0}^\infty{z_k^j}
= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty y^k {z_k^j}
 $.

From here on, it's up to you.
If there is a more explicit form for the $z_k$,
substitute it here and proceed.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can proceed like this.  I'm actually trying to change the formula.  I don't want $\sum{z_k}$ in the result.  I want to transform $\sum{z_k} \to z_k$.